# Enable save button only if all 3 dropdowns are selected

Tags: angular

I have 3 p-dropdowns one each for teacher, student and administrator with more than 500 values in each of the dropdowns. I have a save button common to all these dropdowns. I want to enable the save button only if all 3 dropdowns have been selected. Even if 1 dropdown is not selected the save button needs to be disabled. How do I achieve this in angular and prime NG?

1. I have created a new service to validate each of the 3 fields.
2. I am adding an if condition to check if  the selected item is empty then diable the save button else enable the save button

in .ts file:
    disable(){

```
    if (this.teacher != '' || this.student != '' || this.administrator !='')
    {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
```

in html:

```
<div class="ui-g-10 paddingForm">
    <p-dropdown
        [options]='teacher'  
        (selectedItemChange)='checkActiveTeacher($event , "teacher")'
        [(ngModel)]="teacher" placeholder="Select Option" [filter]="true"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </p-dropdown>
</div>

<button
        label='Save'
        (click)='modifyTeacherAssignment()'
        [disabled]='disable()'
        styleClass='button-action'>
</app-button>
```

modifyTeacherAssignment calls services and pass the data to the service to save the modified teacher data.

Save button should be enabled only if all 3 dropdowns are populated. Right now, save button is getting enabled even if 2 dropdowns are getting populated.

Comment: Add required attribute to the dropdown elements and enable save button only when the form is not pristine and valid...

Comment: The problem with your current logic expression is, that if one it is `true`, it returns `true`. You need to check if all of them are not empty. Furthermore, you need to **initialize** them with empty strings. If not, maybe you aint checking for `undefined` or `null`. So atleast it should be 
`return this.teacher !== '' && this.student !== '' this.administrator !== ''`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here.

**Incorrect closing tag**

First of all. Your `<button>` tag is closed off with `</app-button>`.

---

**Logical error**

It seems like you got the logic the wrong way around. I think you meant to do this:

```
disable() {
  return this.teacher == '' || this.student == '' || this.administrator == '';
}
```

However, it would probably be easier to read if you did something like:

```
canSave() {
  return this.teacher && this.student && this.administrator;
}
```

and

```
<button label='Save' (click)='modifyTeacherAssignment()' [disabled]='!canSave()' styleClass='button-action'></button>
```

---

As @Surjeet Bhadauriya mentions, you can write the logic directly in the attribute of the HTML tag. However, in my opinion, it is considered better practice to separate the logic from the template itself.

Comment: Its not easier to read when you use `disabled` which needs `true` and then you negate the canSave method.

Comment: How does negating the function call make it harder to read? I would prefer to make the logical expression itself easier to read, rather than the actual function call. `disabled if not can save` is pretty straight forward.

Comment: it should be closed off by the <button> tag. The logic doesnt seem to enable the save button. Because even though one of the teachers seem to be inactive in the DB when I do ngModel=[(selectedTeacher)], and print it as {{ selectedTeacher }} the value appears on the screen. Ideally it should be null because the teacher does not exist in the DB.

Comment: Read the directive like a sentence. ' Button is `disabled` when you not can save'. Easier: 'Button is `disabled` when form not complete'. So I would call the method `formNotComplete` and would check if one all of them are not empty and combine it with `&&`. You writing code for the next guy who is reading your code, not for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through your `HTML` only.

**Just add this condition on your button:**

> `[disabled]="!(teacher && student && administrator)"`

```
<button label='Save' [disabled]="!(teacher && student && administrator)" (click)='modifyTeacherAssignment()' [disabled]='disable()' styleClass='button-action'></app-button>
```

**Stackblitz example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-disabled?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: now the save button is not getting enabled at all. The save button should be enabled even if i change one of the dropdowns to a different value and the other 2 dropdowns are selected.

Comment: @Mrunalini First, clarify what you want. Do you want to enable dropdown when any one dropdown is filled or all dropdowns are filled.

Comment: I want to enable dropdown when all dropdowns are filled.

Comment: So I have added an example. Please check it.

Comment: Since when you call `this` inside the html?

Comment: Ya thanks, it's typo mistake. Please check now. Updated the answer as well.

Comment: The first line too :D
`[disabled]="!(teacher && student && administrator)"`
Netherless you aint checking for null, undefined or didnt even know if the variable is empty.

Comment: `dropdown1 = ''; dropdown2 = ''; dropdown3 = '';`
If you add this from your stackblitz to your answer, you are good to go.

Comment: @Surjeet. There is a new problem. We are populating the drop downs from the DB. Some of the teachers are inactive and are not populating in the dropdown. However when we do ngModel = [(selectedTeacher)], even the inactive teacher is getting pulled into the object. Therefore the Save button is getting enabled even though one of the dropdown is not selected. Please provide more information about how to go about fixing this issue.

Comment: @Mrunalini, you can make condition based on that flag like: [disabled]=!(obj1.isActive && obj2.isActive)